# How to make axMozillaBrowser control wait berofe it navigates another web-page

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, mozilla

I am creating a simple web-browser reloader program. In my program I am using these controls

```
axMozillaBrowser,
Button,
progressBar,
TextBox
```

I am trying to load a web page "5" times. Below is my code that works when i use webBrowser control (an instance of internet explorer)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (progressBar1.Value !=5 )
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            while(webBrowser1.ReadyState != webBrowserRedyState.Complete)
            {
            if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == webBrowserRedyState.Complete)
            {
                    progressBar1.Value =+ 1;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 5;
        textBox1.Text = "www.google.com";
    }
}
}
```

This is the code that is not working when I use axMozillaBrowser control (an instance of Mozilla Browser). This doesn't load the web page and it's waiting cursor is just blinking.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (progressBar1.Value !=5 )
        {
            axMozillaBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            while(axMozillaBrowser1.ReadyState != MOZILLACONTROLLib.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            {
            if (axMozillaBrowser1.ReadyState == MOZILLACONTROLLib.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            {
                    progressBar1.Value =+ 1;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 5;
        textBox1.Text = "www.google.com";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if i will not implement wait then it will not load pages properly and it will go f0r second navigation then third & forth. that's why i want it to wait till it completes first time navigation the go for next

Comment: please tell me what i need to do to make axMozillaBrowser control wait till it complets it's first navigation then go for next time nagivation

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser control have Navigated (or something like that) event?
As example, you can use it into simple logic cycle, where your control navigates to first URL in collection, then, when navigation completed, navigate to second URL and next.

upd: sorry, I read it again and can't understand now.
upd2: but I suggest you to find Navigated and Navigating events and NavigationState property.